# how to time an event and output it to the screen with JavaScript

Tags: javascript

I'm a newbie at javascript so please bear with me.

I basically made this quiz where the user answers 10 questions. I've managed to display the what the user wrote as their answer and what their score but I need to output how long they took to complete the quiz and if they take longer than 2 minutes, by default, the quiz should end.

```
<! DOCTYPE>
<html>
<head>
<title>Interactive quiz</title>
</head>

<body>

<input type="button" value="Start the quiz" name="quiz" onclick="startingquiz()">
<p id="answer0"> </p>
<p id="answer1"> </p>
<p id="answer2"> </p>
<p id="answer3"> </p>
<p id="answer4"> </p>
<p id="answer5"> </p>
<p id="answer6"> </p>
<p id="answer7"> </p>
<p id="answer8"> </p>
<p id="answer9"> </p>


<script>
var questions = ["How many awards has 50 cent won? a)73 b)42 c)39", 
"What year did Micheal Jackson die? a)2009 b) 2012 c) 2010",
"How many awards has Drake recieved as of January 2015? a)34 b)36 c) 20",
"What year did Kanye West win his first award? a) 2004 b) 2005 c )2003",
"How old is 50 cent? a)45 b)38 c )39",
"What year did the beatles break up? a)1987 b)1970 c)1966",
"How many sons does 50 cent have? a)4 b)3 c)2",
"When did 2Pac die? a)1996 b)1990 c)1991",
"When did biggie smalls die? a)1997 b)1980 d) 1990",
"when did eazy e die? a)1995 b)1996 c) 1989"];

var userAnswers = [];
var pointCounter = 0;


function startingquiz(){
//Timer is started with no delay. quiz is execcuted through gettingAnswers() method;
var time = setTimeout(gettingAnswers(), 0);
changingBACKGROUND();
//ENDING TIMER
clearTimeout(time);
}

function gettingAnswers (){

for(var i = 0; i < questions.length; i++){
var answers = prompt(questions[i]);
userAnswers[i] = answers;
}

if(userAnswers[0] == "73"){
document.getElementById("answer0").innerHTML = "<p><span class = 'correct'>" + questions[0] + ". You typed in " +userAnswers[0] + ". Correct! +2 points! " + "</span></p>"; 
pointCounter = pointCounter + 2;
}else if(userAnswers[0] == "a"){
document.getElementById("answer0").innerHTML ="<p><span class = 'correct'>" + questions[0] + ". You typed in " +userAnswers[0] + ". Correct! +2 points! " + "</span></p>";
pointCounter = pointCounter + 2;}
else{
document.getElementById("answer0").innerHTML ="<p>" + questions[0] + ". You typed in " +userAnswers[0] + ". Incorrect! -1 points! " + "</p>"; 
pointCounter = pointCounter - 1;
}

if(userAnswers[1] == "2012"){
document.getElementById("answer1").innerHTML = "<p>" + questions[1] + ". You typed in " +userAnswers[1] + ". Correct! +2 points! " + "</p>"; 
pointCounter = pointCounter + 2;
}else if(userAnswers[1] == "a"){
document.getElementById("answer1").innerHTML = "<p>" + questions[1] + ". You typed in " +userAnswers[1] + ". Correct! +2 points! " + "</p>"; 
pointCounter = pointCounter + 2;}
else{
document.getElementById("answer1").innerHTML = "<p>" + questions[1] + ". You typed in " +userAnswers[1] + ". Incorrect! -1 points! " + "</p>"; 
pointCounter = pointCounter - 1;
}

if(userAnswers[2] == "36"){
document.getElementById("answer2").innerHTML = "<p>" + questions[2] + ". You typed in " +userAnswers[2] + ". Correct! +2 points! " + "</p>"; 
pointCounter = pointCounter + 2;
}else if(userAnswers[2] == "b"){
document.getElementById("answer2").innerHTML = "<p>" + questions[2] + ". You typed in " +userAnswers[2] + ". Correct! +2 points! " + "</p>"; 
pointCounter = pointCounter + 2;
}
else{
document.getElementById("answer2").innerHTML = "<p>" + questions[2] + ". You typed in " +userAnswers[2] + ". Incorrect! -1 points! " + "</p>"; 
pointCounter = pointCounter - 1;
}

if(userAnswers[3] == "2004"){
document.getElementById("answer3").innerHTML = "<p>" + questions[3] + ". You typed in " +userAnswers[3] + ". Correct! +2 points! " + "</p>"; 
pointCounter = pointCounter + 2;
}else if(userAnswers[3] == "a"){
document.getElementById("answer3").innerHTML = "<p>" + questions[3] + ". You typed in " +userAnswers[3] + ". Correct! +2 points! " + "</p>";
pointCounter = pointCounter + 2;}
else{
document.getElementById("answer3").innerHTML = "<p>" + questions[3] + ". You typed in " +userAnswers[3] + ". Incorrect! -1 points! " + "</p>";
pointCounter = pointCounter - 1;
}

if(userAnswers[4] == "39"){
document.getElementById("answer4").innerHTML ="<p>" + questions[4] + ". You typed in " +userAnswers[4] + ". Correct! +2 points! " + "</p>"; 
pointCounter = pointCounter + 2;
}else if(userAnswers[4] == "c"){document.getElementById("answer4").innerHTML ="<p>" + questions[4] + ". You typed in " +userAnswers[4] + ". Correct! +2 points! " + "</p>";
pointCounter = pointCounter + 2;}
else{document.getElementById("answer4").innerHTML = "<p>" + questions[4] + ". You typed in " +userAnswers[4] + ". Incorrect! -1 points! " + "</p>"; 
pointCounter = pointCounter - 1;}

if(userAnswers[5] == "1970"){document.getElementById("answer5").innerHTML ="<p>" + questions[5] + ". You typed in " +userAnswers[5] + ". Correct! +2 points! " + "</p>"; 
pointCounter = pointCounter + 2;
}else if(userAnswers[5] == "b"){
document.getElementById("answer5").innerHTML ="<p>" + questions[5] + ". You typed in " +userAnswers[5] + ". Correct! +2 points! " + "</p>";
pointCounter = pointCounter + 2;}
else{document.getElementById("answer5").innerHTML ="<p>" + questions[5] + ". You typed in " +userAnswers[5] + ". Incorrect! -1 points! " + "</p>"; 
pointCounter = pointCounter - 1;}

if(userAnswers[6] == "2"){
document.getElementById("answer6").innerHTML = "<p>" + questions[6] + ". You typed in " +userAnswers[6] + ". Correct! +2 points! " + "</p>"; pointCounter = pointCounter + 2;
}else if(userAnswers[6] == "c"){
document.getElementById("answer6").innerHTML ="<p><span class = 'correct'>" + questions[6] + ". You typed in " +userAnswers[6] + ". Correct! +2 points! " + "</span></p>";pointCounter = pointCounter + 2;}
else{document.getElementById("answer6").innerHTML ="<p>" + questions[6] + ". You typed in " +userAnswers[6] + ". Incorrect! -1 points! " + "</p>"; pointCounter = pointCounter - 1;}

if(userAnswers[7] == "1996"){
document.getElementById("answer7").innerHTML ="<p>" + questions[7] + ". You typed in " +userAnswers[7] + ". Correct! +2 points! " + "</p>"; 
pointCounter = pointCounter + 2;
}else if(userAnswers[7] == "a"){
document.getElementById("answer7").innerHTML ="<p>" + questions[7] + ". You typed in " +userAnswers[7] + ". Correct! +2 points! " + "</p>";
pointCounter = pointCounter + 2;}
else{document.getElementById("answer7").innerHTML ="<p>" + questions[7] + ". You typed in " +userAnswers[7] + ". Incorrect! -1 points! " + "</p>"; 
pointCounter = pointCounter - 1;}

if(userAnswers[8] == "1997"){
document.getElementById("answer8").innerHTML ="<p>" + questions[8] + ". You typed in " +userAnswers[8] + ". Correct! +2 points! " + "</p>"; 
pointCounter = pointCounter + 2;
}else if(userAnswers[8] == "a"){
document.getElementById("answer8").innerHTML ="<p>" + questions[8] + ". You typed in " +userAnswers[8] + ". Correct! +2 points! " + "</p>";
pointCounter = pointCounter + 2;}
else{document.getElementById("answer8").innerHTML ="<p>" + questions[8] + ". You typed in " +userAnswers[8] + ". Incorrect! -1 points! " + "</p>"; 
pointCounter = pointCounter - 1;}

if(userAnswers[9] == "1995"){
document.getElementById("answer8").innerHTML ="<p>" + questions[9] + ". You typed in " +userAnswers[9] + ". Correct! +2 points! " + "</p>"; 
pointCounter = pointCounter + 2;
}else if(userAnswers[9] == "a"){
document.getElementById("answer8").innerHTML ="<p>" + questions[9] + ". You typed in " +userAnswers[9] + ". Correct! +2 points! " + "</p>";
pointCounter = pointCounter + 2;}
else{document.getElementById("answer9").innerHTML ="<p>" + questions[9] + ". You typed in " +userAnswers[9] + ". Incorrect! -1 points! " + "</p>"; 
pointCounter = pointCounter - 1;}

document.getElementById("answer9").innerHTML ="Total point = " + pointCounter;

}

function changingBACKGROUND(){
//CHANGING BACKGROUND
if(pointCounter<5){
document.body.style.backgroundColor="grey";
}else if(pointCounter > 6 && pointCounter <10){
document.body.style.backgroundColor="pink";
}else if(pointCounter > 11){
document.body.style.backgroundColor="blue";
}
}


</script>
</body>
</html>
```

But I have no idea how to stop the quiz if the user takes more than 1 minute.

Comment: have a look at `Date`.

Comment: You could have created a jsfiddle man

Answer (score 0):

You can look into using `setInterval()` and setting the interval timer to 1000 milliseconds

```
var timeElapsed = 0;

var timeInterval = setInterval(function() {
    timeElapsed++;
    console.log(timeElapsed);
}, 1000);
```

In the setInterval callback function, you can change a DOM element to represent the time elapsed and have it stop once it hits whatever number you want it to by calling `clearInterval(timeInterval)`